# Cannot hit test a render box with no size in listview builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have a listviewbuilder with a listtile that looks like this:

[image]

When I scroll this list, it scrolls a bit and then it freezes completely. I checked the logs and am getting this error:

> E/flutter ( 2439): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]
> Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box with no size.

I also get this error:

> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.

Here's the code for list view builder:

```
 return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: productsData.items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (_, i) => Column(
                      children: [
                        UserProductItem(
                          productsData.items[i].id,
                          productsData.items[i].title,
                          productsData.items[i].isAvailable
                           
                        ),
                        Divider(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
```

Will appreciate your help and support.

Comment: By any change you have `SingleChildScrollView()` in your widget? It might be causing the problem. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067082/unhandled-exception-cannot-hit-test-a-render-box-with-no-size

Comment: I don't use SingleChildScrollView

Comment: Possible to show `UserProductItem()`?

Answer (score 4):

Try wrapping your `Padding()` with `Container()` and give height to it. Source [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65830510/11855654)

```
return Container(
  height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  //...
```

Answer (score -2):

Use shrinkWrap, if your ListView isn’t too big

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true, // use it
    )
  ],
)
```